# Regression - set factor level to predefined value

Tags: r, glm

How can I set a factor level to a predefined value in a regression model?

I can't seem to use the `offset` function on a factor variable when specifying a regression model using `lm`. For example, to set the constraint `Sepal.Width = 0.5` where `Sepal.Width` is a continuous variable I would code

```
lm(Sepal.Length ~ as.factor(Species) + offset(Sepal.Width*0.5), data = iris)
```

How can I set, say, the first level of `Species` (which is called `setosa`) equal to a predefined value of five? I.e. how to constrain the regression model above to `setosa = 5`.

Comment: Maybe you could try `as.factor(as.integer(Species) + 5)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is achieved by this. It seems that we're just renaming the levels of the factor. E.g. instead of levels 1, 2 and 3 we get levels 6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the model matrix and work in terms of that:

```
mm <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length ~ Species - 1, iris)
fm <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ mm[, -1] + offset(.5 * mm[, 1]) - 1, iris)
```

**Revised**

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked correctly. When I compare two identical models, one that is fitted in Stata and the other one in R, I get different results. In Stata I would define a constraint on the first level of `Species` as `constraint define constrFirstLvl _b[1.Species] = 0.5`, and then run the regression command `regress Sepal.Length i.Species, constraints(constrFirstLvl)`. What I'm seeing is that the likelihoods of the constrained models in Stata and R differ, which results in different estimates.